# First onBackPressed close DrawerLayout if is open and in second onBackPressed intent to another activity

Tags: android, onkeydown, onbackpressed

How can i change my cod that on the first back pressed close drawer Layout if is open and in second back pressed intent to another activity if drawer is close ?

my drowrlayout is :

```
 drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.downMenu);
                if (m == false) {
                    m = true;
                    drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                } else {
                    m = false;
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check for it in `onBackPressed()`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    } else {
       // DO your stuff here 
    }
}
```

Change the `GravityCompat` as per your need if you are using left drawer then it will be as `GravityCompat.START` .

Answer (score 0):

`onBackPressed() if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
  //drawer is open
} else { startActivity(...)}` the 1st condition will check drawer is open or not ...

Comment: Thank you for your support.